# Why does stopping my service kill the foreground activity?

Tags: android, service

In my app's main activity, I start a service like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(i);
```

When the user presses a button, I stop the service like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
stopService(i);
```

When I do this, the foreground activity that's making the call is killed and disappears.

Thinking that maybe the service needed to run in a separate process, I tried setting android:process=":remote" on the service in the manifest, but that didn't change the behavoir.

It seems that I can't stop the service without killing the entire app. Is there a way around this?

Comment: This isn't normal behavior. Start ddms, recreate the bug, and post log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why the app was being killed. In my service's onDestroy() method, I was disabling a broadcast receiver like this:

```
PackageManager pacman = getPackageManager();
pacman.setComponentEnabledSetting(
     new ComponentName(this, MyReceiver.class), 
     PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
     0);
```

This code disables a broadcast receiver that is defined in AndroidManifest.xml. The last argument, 0, should have been set to DONT_KILL_APP. I changed the code to this, and it solved the problem:

```
PackageManager pacman = getPackageManager();
pacman.setComponentEnabledSetting(
     new ComponentName(this, MyReceiver.class), 
     PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
     PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without logs we can't know for sure but I have a good hunch that your app is throwing an exception and that you are silently catching and closing or you have an odd critical path that call `finish`.

In any case, what you described is not expected but we need more info to give a better answer

Comment: Good suggestions, but I checked for silent catch blocks, and improper calls to finish(), and found nothing.